# React component and CSS: style items in the same element differently

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a React component named "Badge" returning some Text that is styled bold.

```
render() {
 return (
  <div>
   <Text weight={'bold'}>
    {this.props.label}
   </Text>
  </div>
)
```

Now, I use "Badge" in another component named "Card".

Because in Badge component all Text is styled bold, the whole sentence is bold as well:

```
return (
 <div>
  <Badge lable={'This part of the sentence is ' + 'normal font style' + ' and the rest is bold.'}></Badge>
 </div>
)
```

Now, I would like to style the items in this element differently:  I want to remove the bold style from 'normal font style' - only for this single part of the string. I already tried this way, but it doesn't work:

```
<Badge label={'This part of the sentence is ' + <span class=”normalText”>'normal font style'</span> + ' and the rest is bold.'}></Badge>
```

As an absolute beginner, this problem is driving me crazy. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: try using `className` instead of `class`.

Comment: Expose the Text `weight` prop to your `Badge` API, i.e. `<Badge label='This is bolded text!' weight='bold' />`

Comment: Does the `Badge` do anything other than contain s div and a `Text` component? Perhaps you could rewrite it a bit to be more of a container and it simply renders whatever children it contains (with whatever style they may have).

Comment: Hello Drew, the problem is, I am not allowed to modify the badge component. I have to use it as it is :(

Comment: Well then you may have to create a new component then as React will pretty much escape everything it renders (save for some judicious use of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` which wouldn't work here as the Badge is only rendering a label into another react component). Why are you barred from modifying `Badge`?

Comment: Thanks, Drew, then I will do it this way. Head of my departure says I am not allowed to modify badge. No further explanations :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the `text` with `html` tag then you have to pass all the text/tags in `html` form. Check below code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM,{ render } from 'react-dom';
import Badge from './Badge';
import './style.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>       
       <Badge label="test" /><br/>
       <Badge label={'This part of the sentence is ' + 'normal font style' + ' and the rest is bold.'} /><br/>
       <Badge label={<>
          <span>This part of the sentence is</span> <span className="normalText">'normal font style'</span> <span> and the rest is bold.</span> 
        </>}
       />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have created small demo for you.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rvuqv6

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, this version throws the error: "Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'."

Comment: I am using custom component where pass details in `label` as `props`. If you are still facing same issue then please let me know the name of package for `Text` or `Badge`.

Answer (score 0):

The more appropriate system is take label value as badge's children. to declare Badge component code like this example:

```
const Badge = props => {
    return (
       <div className={`badge-class`}>
          <Text weight={'bold'}>
              {props.children}
          </Text>
       </div>
    )
}
```

and now call the component like this

```
return (
   <div>
      <Badge>
          This part of the sentence is <span className={`normal-texts`}>normal font style</span> and the rest is bold.
      </Badge>
   </div>
)
```

with this you can pass any type children on Badge component, text, image etc.